# Detect being last child control and change one property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a stackpanel with many listboxes and all except the last one should have background visible. Is it possible to detect from ControlTemplate that listbox is the last child and set "Bd" opacity to 0. (MyListBox extends Listbox)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyListBox}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyListBox}">
             <Grid >
             ...
                <Border Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Bd"...>
                   <Border.Background>
                      <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/arrayProba1;component/bck/mybck.png" />
                   </Border.Background>
```

If I add another Listbox, the old one that was previously last child will get background and the new one will loose it setting "Bd" opacity 0 (will be animated later)

```
private List<MyListBox> MyPanels = new List<MyListBox>();

MyPanels.Add(new MyListBox() { Title = "..." });
MyPanelsHolder.Children.Add(MyPanels[n]);
```

I had it working creating whole style in code behind, but I need to do it this way. 
How would you approach this problem?

Comment: I would create a bd Color property in my object, set the last item transparent, and simply bind it. I try to avoid all direct manipulation of Items Control / List Box items.

Comment: You mean create bool MyOpacity DependencyProperty in MyListBox class and then in Bd bind Opacity="{TemplateBinding MyOpacity}"? That way after I add new MyListBox I could iterate through MyPanels and set MyOpacity in all of them to 0 and set the last to 1. It seems like a good idea, is that how you meant?

Comment: Yes. Always preffer to have properties and set them on your object properties in code behind. Then Bind them on XAML, or use WPF Triggers. Then the change will be visible in user interface with the use of INotifyPropertyChanged on your class.

Comment: Thank you. It is always good to hear the proper way to do things in wpf since everything can be improvised in so many ways.

Comment: Welcome. Yes, but to make simple, you have XAML, then in code-behind, you have you class with properties, that are Binded to WPF Controls. With this you avoid manipulation of VisualTree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tony this how I did it in the end... 
That border is now

```
<Border Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsNotCurrent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
  <Border.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/arrayProba1;component/Bck/MyBck.png" />
```

And in MyListBox class I have:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNotCurrentProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("IsNotCurrent", typeof(bool),
  typeof(MyListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool IsNotCurrent
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(IsNotCurrentProperty); }
  set { SetValue(IsNotCurrentProperty, value); }
}
```

So every time I add or remove a listBox I set all MyPanels[i].IsNotCurrent = true; and set the last one to 'false'.

I might change it all to affirmative version later (instead IsNotCurrent to IsLast)